# Does calling a regular .net assembly from COM+ mean the benefits of COM+ are lost?

Tags: .net, com+

I have a vb6 component that hosted in com+ that makes several calls to a .net assembly on same machine to fetch data. This .net assembly is very simple and does not derive from ServicedComponent and is simply exposed as Com.

Does using a .net assembly in this way mean that the .net component is not getting any of the benefits of com+ pooling etc and making all my calls to it likely very slow as .net assembly getting recreated fresh each time?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the assembly is doing. COM+ gives you many advantages doing things like transaction management, context flow between machines, pooling, etc. However if this assembly of yours is simply reading a file or something like that, then it doesn't really matter if your VB6 DLL is hosted in COM+ or not.

Now if the .NET assembly is talking to a database or some such then yes, it becomes "enlisted" in the COM+ context and transaction (if any) and you are getting the benefits of COM+.